# Getting Null reference/ HandleEntityAppendOnly error while eager loading

Tags: entity-framework-5

The solution to this nut seems to elude me :-)

We have a method that eager loads some related entities and this works fine when it is hosted in a local IIS-instance on our development machines (Windows 7 Enterprise, 64-bitSP1, VS2012SP3 with solution built against Net 4.5) 
However, when we run it hosted in IIS on a server (Windows 2008 R2 Standard SP1) it fails with the following error:

```
   2013-09-27 08:42:09,950 ERROR@27[rastructrure.Repositories.SäkerhetsorderRepository] Fel i SäkerhetsorderRepository.AllMatching()
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(Type type)
   at Kororder.Domain.Aggregat.Säkerhetsorder.Säkerhetsorder..ctor()
   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Kororder.Infrastructrure.Repositories.SäkerhetsorderRepository.AllMatching(ISpecification`1 specification)
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE, I forgot the topmost line in the error that we log

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message, you are using log4net and the `LogManager` instance seems to be null. Might be a configuration issue because usually you define your log4net configuration within the web.config

Comment: Hi Ela, thanks for your quick feedback:
two things: 
1) My initial post did not contain the top line of the error that we recieve, but it does now
2) The error seems to occur when Entity framework tries to instantiate the Säkerhetsorder-entity by calling its ctor

Comment: still the same thing, `rastructrure.Repositories.SäkerhetsorderRepository` is your custom code I guess, this needs a logger from LogManager whichi s a log4net class and it seems to be null. Compare config files or debug it, check for null reference in code...